# Is there a solution for this problem "can't find a usable init.tcl" after converting to executable?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tcl

I converted my .py to exe by auto-py-to-exe , and worked good on my computer, when i tried to run it on another computer didn't run and found that problem:    "File "tkinter_*init*_.py" line 2261, in **init**
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories: {Path\tcl} {path\tcl8.6} ........
This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed proberly
[11340] failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception."
So i don't where's the problem (application or windows), especially the application worked fine on more computers except that computer
Thank you

Comment: What is the app about, what are your `import`, what is the `auto-py-to-exe` code used

Comment: From _tkinter import TclError

Comment: Although i deleted from _tkinter import TclError from code , i found the same problem

Comment: You can try the `pyinstaller` to convert .py file to .exe. You need to install with `pip install pyinstaller` then the usage is `pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --icon=icon.ico main.py`.  [You can find the syntax in here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html)

Comment: Tkinter (or rather some of its dependencies) truly loathes being packaged like that. I'm working on a fix (it's in alpha) but the fix is _subtly_ complicated because of how it treads on the toes of quite a lot of other use cases.